# Problem of abstracting two things into one

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice, mathematics, formality

As I am having some new options to describe one of my earlier post regarding to the following two constructions making into one sentence, I want to post this once again with my options.

If I say main two things which I want to include separately,

> 1. Testing of previously fixed edge and currently fixed edge is done in order to
>          maintain the correct alignment of the boundary segments.
> 2. previously fixed edge and currently fixed edge are relevant to the two successive 
>          corners but associated with a same polygon.

after joining above 2 into one sentence I have following options

> - Testing of previously fixed edge and currently fixed edge,
>     relevant to
>     the two successive corners but associated with a same polygon, is done
>     in order to maintain the correct alignment of the boundary segments.
> - Testing of the previously fixed edge and the currently fixed edge
>     is
>      done to maintain the correct alignment of the boundary segments; these
>      edges refer to two successive corners associated with a same polygon.
> - Currently fixed edge is compared with the previous fixing which
>     is
>       relevant to the predecessor of the current corner and associated with
>       the same polygon in order to maintain the correct alignment of the
>       boundary segments.

AS this point is very important for my writing, I want your assistant to say this in a formal way.

Comment: I'd love to help, but, even with the figure, I'm still having trouble understanding what you are trying to describe. First, the "currently fixed edge" and the "previously fixed edge" both look like same edge. Why is one previous and the other current? Are Corner 1 and Corner 2 part of two different polygons, and the segment is moved, with one endpoint remaining in the same place, and the other end point moving from Corner 1 to Corner 2? That's my best interpretation, but I don't want to go any further until I know for sure that's the correct way to interpret what you're trying to say.

Comment: By the way, your middle sentence reads rather well. Also, are you working in stereolithography, by chance?

Comment: @J.R.: Thanks for the cooperation. I am fixing one corner after the other and finally I want to get a rectangle having crossed diagonals. I showed one side of it. I am fixing this iteratively.

Comment: Also, can you tell us what you mean by "[fixed](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fix)"? The word "fixed" can mean "repaired," or it can mean "put into an immovable position". In this context, those would be opposite meanings! You might "fix" (repair) an edge by moving it, or you might "fix" (affix) an edge by not allowing it to be moved.

Comment: @J.R.: Thanks for the cooperation. I am fixing one corner after the other and finally I want to get a rectangle having crossed diagonals. I am fixing this iteratively. say now i am in the ith incident. so i showed it as above. so, i got previously fixed end from the i-1 case. current fixed edge by the ith case. corner 1 and corner 2 also from the i-1 and i the case.yes you are right. these previously fixed and curretnly fixed edges should refer to the same edge in the final rectangle. but, in the data it was split. so i should align them as previous and current edge.

Comment: @J.R.: This triangular section is ¼ of the rectangle and name as a segment. So these previous and current edges should be referred to the same segment. That’s why I said so.

Comment: @J.R.: May be if i put all my description you could undestand. withing the process the parts you said chain reaction also included.

Comment: @J.R.: yes fixed mean not movable. once i fixed, again i have to fixed it due to some mis alignment.

Comment: Typically, unless it's destructive testing, *testing* does not change anything about the item under test it simply verifies that the measured result is equal to the expected result.  So it's not the testing that maintains the alignment it's some sort of adjustment that is made based on the result of testing.  So you might say, "Adjustments based on testing are made to maintain the alignment ..."  The interesting things here are the adjustment algorithm and the test procedure.

Comment: But I think this is getting very far afield from ELL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second of your choices is not bad, if you break it into two shorter sentences, and fix some minor problems with articles.  (The struck-through words would be deleted, the italicized words added.)

> Testing of <del>the</del> *a* previously-fixed edge and the currently-fixed edge is done to maintain <del>the</del> correct alignment of <del>the</del> boundary segments.  These edges are parts of <del>two</del> successive corners associated with a <del>same</del> *single* polygon.

The first and third choices either don't make sense or are too convoluted to be worth including.  That is, they do not communicate well enough to be worth room on the page; people will understand things better if you just leave out sentences like the first and third.

Rather than trying to jam everything into a single long sentence, try to write using several short and clear sentences that follow in logical succession.

Comment: I like this answer, although I would leave in the word _two_ in the expression "two successive corners." I realize "successive" sort of implies "two", but this is hard enough to visualize that I think the word "two" could be included in this particular case. Also, @niro: I would include a LOT of figures in your paper, if you're able to include them without going over your page limit.